# Create elements in a new document using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Using plain JavaScript (without jquery), I can open a new window (or tab) and write a minimal HTML document into that window like this:

```
var minimal = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n' +
 '<html>\n' +
 '<head>\n' +
 '<meta charset="utf-8">\n' +
 '<title>Title Here</title>\n' +
 '</head>\n' +
 '<body>\n' +
 '</body>\n' +
 '</html>\n';

var win = window.open();
var doc = win.document;
doc.open('text/html', true);
doc.write(minimal);
doc.close();
```

Then I can use plain JavaScript to dynamically create and add children elements to the new document like this:

```
var body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var div = doc.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'Hi Mom!';
body.appendChild(div);
```

Notice in the above code that I am using `doc` and not `document` which creates a div in the new document.

My understanding of jquery is that this code

```
var div = $('<div/>');
```

will create a div in the current document and not in the new document, and a div created in the current document cannot be added to the new document. Is there some way to get jquery to create elements in a new document as shown in my plain JavaScript code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamically creating DOM elements without attaching/parenting them to other DOM elements will be discarded.

```
var div = $('<div></div>');  // will create a div and wait for you to append it
```

so you can say:

```
div.appendTo("body");  // this will append it body
```

or you could say:

```
div.appendTo(win.document);   // the div will be appended somewhere else
```